# test cases for conversation unsubscription in a email

Tags: test-design, email

I am a newbie at testing.

The scenario described here is what happens when a user tries to unsubscribe from a conversation using Mailing list manager.

To unsubscribe the user sends an email sample+unsubscribe@domain.com.
The subject would usually contain unsubscribe.

I have some test cases which I can work on, but since this is my first attempt, I feel that I am possibly missing some of the more obvious ones. Are there any guidelines or procedures which I can refer to test the above scenario?

The following are some of the test cases that I have come up with :

1. if the email specifies that it is for unsubscription, the contents in the subject can be unsub, blank as well as UNSUBCRIPTION. I should be able to ignore the case of the subject and handle abbreviations
2. usually unsubscribe messages are sent to a particular email address. But it is quite possible that the user forgets this and sends the email to a regular email id, asking for unsubscription. I should still be able to unsubscribe the user from a conversation
3. I should specifically ignore the body of a message.
4. The unsubscription message should not bounce back to the sender.

I am not sure if I am missing any more test cases, any input will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, bhavs.  Perhaps you could describe the use case in more detail.  I suspect most of us are familiar with an unsubscribe operation, but describing some specifics in your own words may help with the test cases.  For example, you said "the subject would *usually* contain `unsubscribe`.  What are the other possibilities?

Comment: @user246 thanks for your suggestions I have updated the above question with some test cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the limited information available related to scenario, following are list of few other test cases that can be validated -

What If:

1. User sends an email for unsubscription but user is not a registered user.
2. User subscribes and unsubscribes immediately
3. Same unsubscription requests come multiple times
4. Same unsubscription requests come at the same time
5. User tries to subscribe again after unsubscription
6. Unsubscription request is coming at peak load
7. Subject contain "***unsub***" not as a word but as sub string

Comment: thanks rahul this makes sense to me, i will probably take this ahead and extend it

Answer (score 0):

What do you have so far for test cases?  Hard to say what might be missing without knowing what is covered.

I notice you said you think you are missing something.  What do you think you are missing?  Is there something that sticks out to you?  Or that you are asking yourself 'but what if...'?  Those are the areas I would start.